# xcode/swift error: could not find member "row"

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

I keep getting this error: "could not find member row".
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var myList: Array<AnyObject>  = []

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")

    myList = context.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)!
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "update" {
        //GETTING ERROR ON THIS NEXT LINE//
        var selectedItem: NSManagedObject = 
                myList[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row!] as! NSManagedObject

        let IVC: ItemViewController = 
                     segue.destinationViewController as! ItemViewController

        IVC.item = selectedItem.valueForKey("item") as! String
        IVC.quantity = selectedItem.valueForKey("quantity") as! String
        IVC.info = selectedItem.valueForKey("info") as! String
        IVC.existingItem = selectedItem
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me get rid of that error.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` you are getting back a `NSIndexPath` instance, not an integer.  You then need to ask that `NSIndexPath` for its row.  So the call should read `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row()`

This is of course assuming you only have one section in your table view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selectedItem = myList[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row] as! NSManagedObject
```